# Workflow not showing up in GitHub Actions

Tags: github, yaml, pytest, github-actions

I am doing a continuous integration workflow in GitHub Actions to trigger "pytest backend/tests/" command on a push to any branch. Right now, I am testing in a feature branch. The pytest.yml file is located in /.github/workflows/. The GitHub actions is not showing my workflow, even after I push new changes.

This is my pytest.yml file

```
name: Run pytest on push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '*'

jobs:
  pytest:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.9

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: pip install -r requirements.txt

    - name: Run pytest
      run: pytest backend/tests
```

Comment: may I know your feature branch name?

Comment: on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'

Add another asterik so that it matches all the branches.

single asteric matches every branch except branches containaing '/'

Comment: my feature branch is called IG-28-feature/continuous-integration

Comment: can you try to another asterik in your branch filter?

Comment: single asterik will not match branches with "/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your workflow will not show up in the Actions tab until it's merged to the main branch.

The reason is because certain triggers (like `push`, `workflow_dispatch`) requires the new workflow to be merged to main branch first before showing up in Actions tab.

So to solve this, you can instead use the `pull_request` trigger, like:

```
on:
  pull_request:
```

Then the action should come up in the Actions tab, even before you merge your changes to the main branch.

Answer (score 1):

try this -

'*' - Matches all the branches except branches containg slashes ("/")

'**' - Matches all the branches

```
name: Run pytest on push

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
```